# Select union only if @variable is emply, using SQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have a stored procedure with the following UNION SELECT. I want the second select to run only if @name is empty.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spNames]
@name NVARCHAR(20)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT names FROM namesTbl1
UNION SELECT names FROM namesTbl2 //This should run only if @name = ''
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `if`.  But if you want a single query:

```
SELECT names FROM namesTbl1
UNION
SELECT names FROM namesTbl2 WHERE @name = '';
```

Note:  because you are using `UNION`, this will remove duplicates (if any) from the first table.  So, `if` is more efficient:

```
if (@name = '')
begin
    SELECT names FROM namesTbl1;
end;
else
begin
    SELECT names FROM namesTbl1
    UNION
    SELECT names FROM namesTbl2;
end;
```